# On hover/mouseover text does not move with in-page scroll bar

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm using some on hover content to give additional data to an abbreviated header as such:

[On hover normally](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sgjzU.png)

However, when I use the scrollbar the text moves across the page as such:

[When I use the scrollbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aIKHO.png)

This is a regular table with HTML, CSS, Javascript:

```
<th style="text-align:center;">
<div>
NYITKG3
</div>
<div class="popup" >
Joyride Green Tea RTD Keg
</div>
</th>
```

```
$(".cell").mouseover(function() {
$(this).children(".popup").show();
}).mouseout(function() {
$(this).children(".popup").hide();
});
```

```
.popup {
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    border:1px solid #000;
    width:100px;
    color: black;
    background: white;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

see here :

**[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Mihai_T/08cevuw3/2/)**

you need to set a `relative` position to an element so the `absolute` popup stays relative to that element and why use JQ when you can use css ?

```
.cell { 
  position:relative;
 }
 .cell:hover .popup { 
 display:block
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out the answer is fairly simple. If you want your absolutely positioned element to stay within its parent as you use an in-page scroll bar, you just need to add `position:relative;` into the css of the parent div as such:

```
<th style="text-align:center;position:relative;">
<div>
NYITKG3
</div>
<div class="popup" >
Joyride Green Tea RTD Keg
</div>
</th>
```

Now the hover text will scroll with the table.